# How to change the position of the SLIDEIN animation of the panel in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a custom panel and now I added animation for the panel to be show on button click. Problem now is the start & stop positions of the animation. I want to set the position from where to start the animation and where to end it.

Now am doing this way

`showAnimation: {
            type: 'slideIn',
            direction: 'up',
            duration: 400,
            easing: 'ease',
            listeners: {
                animationend: function(evt, obj) {
          // my code here
                }
            }
        }`

This shows the popup from the bottom of the screen but I don't want to come all the way from bottom of the screen. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `showAnimation`, you can use `Ext.Animator.run`.
Here is the sample:

```
Ext.Animator.run({
    element: this.getNavigation().element, // this.getYourViewObject().element
    duration: 500,
    easing: 'ease-in',
    preserveEndState: true,
    from: {
       top: document.body.clientHeight // Max Height i.e Bottom
     },
     to: {
        top: 0 // Height where you want to stop your Slide View
     }
 });
```

If you still don't get it, feel free to comment. I'll make you a Demo.

Comment: Cool. This works for me. Thanks for your help. This is what I was looking for. I accepted your answer and 1up. Thank you

Comment: Works fine but I just noticed animation. It is not smooth as 'slideIn' animation. It has some flickering.

Comment: can u fix this flickering effect? please

Comment: Did you notice that 'duration'? If you want fast and smooth animation reduce it.Let's say, reduce it to 250 or 300 and see the effect.

Comment: regardless of duration, there's always some flickering in the animation.

Comment: Actually I can't see that as I'm testing in Chrome's Emulator.

Comment: yes, it animates smooth on browser while testing on browsers. It has flickering effect when run on device

Comment: I think it's working great in my Android Device.Means I can't find flickering effect.

Comment: I tested on both iOS and android devices. mobile, tab everything has flickering. Working to fix it...